# Sync UI Updates with Terminal

Tags: linux-mint, software-updates

I've noticed that when I see the update icon on my Linux Mint  19 machine

[image: [img here]]

that it doesn't go to the check sign after running:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

the icon still remains as showing it needs updates - is there a way to manually update it (a.k.a `Refresh` button from the terminal)

[image]